# When does Q = m(h2 - h1) hold true?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, thermodynamics, heat-transfer

From the first law of thermodynamics:

$$\Delta U = Q_{12} - W_{12}$$

where $\Delta U = m(u_2-u_1)$, $W = p(V_2 - V_1)$ with constant pressure, and $Q = m(h_2-h_1)$.

In the energy rate form of the first law simplification for a turbine (or compressor): $\left(\dfrac{\partial E}{\partial t}=0=-W'+m'[h_1-h_2]\right)$

$W' = m'(h_1-h_2)$ while assuming that there's no heat transfer $\left(Q'\right)$ and change in potential and kinetic energy is zero.  ($W'$ is power, or $\dfrac{\partial W}{\partial t}$)

I think I must be missing something obvious here, but it seems inconsistent that $Q' = 0 = m'(h_1-h_2)$ while using $(h_2-h_1)$ in the equation.  Shouldn't $h_2 = h_1$ in both equations?

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! I've edited your question to use MathJax, which makes math more readable (it's basically LaTeX, if you're familiar with that). I replaced your use of W* and Q* with W' and Q', respectively, since that's a more common representation of derivatives. I made a judgment call on your W' and Q' equations that when you'd used `W* = m*(...)`, that was also meant as a derivative (mass flow rate), not as `m [times] (...)` (since you'd previously used simply `m(...)` for multiplication). Please review your post and make any [edit]s you think necessary.

Comment: Oh looks much better thanks